# Prevent R code autocomplete for "%>%" in Visual Studio Code from suggesting "%in%"

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, vscode-r

When using the R Extension for Visual Studio Code the code completion always suggests `%in%` for a line that ends with the magrittr pipe `%>%`. The final `%` in `%>%` triggers an autocomplete suggestion of `%in%`.

Here's what happens when writing a code block:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    select(mpg, cyl) %>%
```

[image]

Is there anyway to fix this? If I type "enter" for a newline like I normally would in any other text editor, visual studio code inserts the `%in%` at the end of the line, which clearly isn't what I want.

I'm not sure where I can tweak any configurations - whether in visual studio code, or the [R extension](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R), or the [R language server](https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver).

Comment: Do you type `%>%` by hand or a keyboard shortcut? I set a shortcut for `%>%` in vscode and never meet this issue.

Comment: I type `%>%` by hand.

Comment: You could add `"editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsed",` to your settings.json so that it recommends what you've used most recently? Options for this setting are _first_, _recentlyUsed_, and _recentlyUsedByPrefix_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the accepted answer isn't useful (whereas MangoHands comment is), I'm reposting his comment as a separate answer:

You can disable the acceptance of suggestions via the `enter` button which and instead use (only) tab to accept suggestions, which I find intuitive.

To this end add the following line into the `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` option from visual studio (Use `Ctrl+Shift+P`/`Cmd+Shift+P` to open the command palette and search for `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`):

`"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": false`

PS: Using the shortcut for the pipe (`Cmd+Shift+M`) is cute until you realize that it won't work in the terminal - at least noy in `radian`- (instead you shift to the 'problems' tab), which for me is a huge and annoying issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your `settings.json`. It should prevent from suggestion of unnecessary strings comments and also `%>%` or `%in%`.

```
  "[r]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "other": false,
      "comments": false,
      "strings": false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Your suggestion turned off suggestions altogether, but I could trigger suggestions with control + space.

I decided to use `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"` as a compromise.